# Make a library that extends a library

Tags: typescript

So I would like to create a library that extends an other library.
I know I can do it like that:

```
declare module "other-lib" {
    interface ExistingClass {
        newFunction(): void;
    }
}

ExistingClass.prototype.newFunction = function() {
    console.log("Ok");
}
```

It works, I can then use the `newFunction` etc. But only when the file containing these declarations are inside the package.

My current setup is:

```
|_ my-lib # contains declarations
|_ my-app # has a reference to `my-lib`
```

The thing is, in `my-app`, **i can't do `ExitingClass.newFunction()`**, but in `my-lib` i can.
Am I missing something ?
Is this even possible to achieve that ?

Note: I use tsup, with dts enabled, and in `package.json`, `types` is set to `dist/index.d.ts`. I can use interfaces etc defined there, but not the module declaration that extends `ExistingClass`

Edit: [this typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFsE8FoBsEsBGwDOAnAxseA7AJgKYAeAdAC4oBQhGsAhmgRAPZ4CusTARM2QBYE0cJF1ABvSqCmhcZQQDM6GJgFEi8FGVwBzAML0UKcZOmmcBAO4AxNjgxbmOABQBKAFygAbs3h4A3CZSAL6UIZRqGlo4egYoJAAOaLy8kPEEJObWtvbwjqAAvKDy2Q7OLsamGI4ozJwksMzaTlwA8gDWXC4BYSC9ff0DgwOUIBAwCMh4kdj4xCR45FQ09Iws7JygPPyCwoiiEqayCkqq6po6%20nSGFabSmTZ2pa4e3r4BpiE9Q98--SNgUF2wHiSjadG06QAVjUcJQuGRUgQUFwPFwppoZoRSAsKFxKP9foShv8xtA6PF4qhMJi5hRKPBwPFmGgyJtARMuAEGUyWeJQBFztFLtcgkUkuBNrwBEIOQFwmcojErnF7iVcmVQKMAApJNIsyCgADkqse6sNoDwzCRoBwvFAxEioDyCLSRoFiuFKEN%20KJvuGo0B5MpIIwYIhJGhjjhhDSszs8CRKJuUi47JEqIQODabhIJGAab2oSAA) might help

Comment: Move your declarations up a folder.

Comment: yes but i want to publish this library to npm, atm i'm developping it for `my-app` because i realized i needed something like that and it doesn't exists yet

Comment: Your library has to be compiled into set of .js files to be consumable by other JS project, and it also needs to have and expose .d.ts files to be consumable by IDE/compiler/etc. Both steps can be done via `tsc` compiler, just add `"declaration": true` to `tsconfig.json` and `"types": "dist/index.d.ts"` to `package.json` (actual name might be different -- it really depends on your project setup etc.).

Comment: yes, i'm using tsup with dts turned on and the module declaration is in index.d.ts as expected, but still can't do `existingClassInstance.newFunction()` outside `my-lib`

Comment: Does the consuming code (`my-app`) have an `import "my-lib"` statement anywhere?  What causes `my-lib` to execute at runtime?  A concrete example / actual reproduction might be helpful.

Comment: yes it does, i'll edit my answer to add more context

Comment: @stevancorre Did you ever get this working? I am looking into doing something similar and running into the same issues.